# Regex: Cannot find a line that contain a string in one place, but it finds the line if the string is in other place on the same line

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this regex, it finds only the meta html tag that contain at least 3 of this words.

**`<meta name="description" content=.*(( the | that | of ).*){3,}.*>`**

**The problem:**

I have this 2 similar lines. Both have the same words, except the second line, where **the** is in a different place. So why does my regex finds only the second line, and not also the first line? How can I change the regex so as to find both lines?

`<meta name="description" content="the mystery of the art that seeks its meaning.">`

`<meta name="description" content="the mystery of art that seeks the its meaning.">`

Comment: Obligatory [using regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such search, you have to use positive lookahead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<meta name="description" content="(?=[^">]*?\bthe\b)(?=[^">]*?\bthat\b)(?=[^">]*?\bof\b )[^">]*">`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<meta name="description" content="      # literally
(?=                                     # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    [^">]*?                                 # 0 or more any character that is not " or >
    \b                                      # word boundary
    the                                     # the word the
    \b                                      # word boundary
)                                       # end lookahead
(?=[^">]*?\bthat\b)                     # same for the word that
(?=[^">]*?\bof\b )                      # same for the word of
[^">]*                                  # 0 or more any character that is not " or >
">                                      # literally
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first line has the words `of` and `the` together and you are searching for the three words with spaces before and after. Try inserting another word between `of` and `the`

Instead of putting actual spaces on your regex like `... WORD ...`  try with word boundaries like `...\bWORD\b...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I find another solution:

**`<meta name="description" content=.*(\b(the|that|of)\b.*){3,}.*>`**

Comment: Be aware that matches `<meta name="description" content="the mystery, the art and the mystery again.">` You see, 3 times `the` but no `that` nor `of`

Comment: That's exactly the solution I proposed in my answer

Comment: @golimar I believe you didn't give any concret solution, but just an indication, a general idea of how can be done. Of course, was a start. Thanks. But next time, please write a concrete solution with an example for the case. Right now, if I copy what you had write in the answer, I cannot resolve my problem. You should write that in a comment, not in a answer.

Comment: @JustMe It is an answer, only that it is not code, but explained with words, and you did exactly what I explained and it worked. That's why I wrote it in an answer and not in a comment

Comment: No, I did not. :) Your `\bWORD\b` it can be formulated in a million ways, search google. That is a usual match case. I can write also `(\bthe\b|\bthat\b|\bof\b)` and other one milion examples with your  `\bWORD\b`. And none would work. Anyway, you will see yourself if you will get votes for your answer...